# Read metadata from image formats not supported by exif_read_data

Tags: php, image, metadata, exif

I'm currently using [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) to load the information from JPG, JPEG, TIFF and TIF files.

Is there a simple way to manually read other images (ex. PNG, BMP, GIF)? Using [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php), or something similar?

Comment: GIF and BMP don't have meta data. PNG very seldomly. Or do you just want height and width?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190236/how-can-i-read-png-metadata-from-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093393/fastest-way-to-read-png-metadata-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BMP and GIF don't support any metadata I believe.

May be you want to find out, if there are any metadata readable at all, before finding the way to read it.

Comment: Not completely true. At least you can add XMP to GIF Application Extension block